# Logstash ignoring multiple date filters

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

i'm making a logstash .conf, and on my filter i need to extract the weekday of two timestamps, but Logstash act as if he only is making one match, example:

```
Timestamp 1: Mar 7, 2019 @ 23:41:40.476 .  => Thursday

Timestamp 2: Mar 1, 2019 @ 15:22:47.209 .  => Thu
```

Expected Output

```
Timestamp 1: Mar 7, 2019 @ 23:41:40.476 .  => Thursday

Timestamp 2: Mar 1, 2019 @ 15:22:47.209 .  => Fri
```

These are my filters:

```
date {
    match => ["[system][process][cpu][start_time]", "dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss", "ISO8601"]
    target => "[system][process][cpu][start_time]"
    add_field => {"[Weekday]" => "%{+EEEEE}"}
  }
date {
    match => ["[FechaPrimero]", "dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss", "ISO8601"]
    target => "[FechaPrimero]"
    add_field => {"[WeekdayFirtsDay]" => "%{+EE}"}
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because by default *%{+EEEEE}* and *%{+EE}* take into account the **@timestamp** field, and no a user made field (don't know it is written in the doc)

The only way of doing that, as far as I know, is using a part of ruby code, to extract day of week, as following :

```
ruby {
  code => 'event.set("Weekday", Time.parse(event.get("[system][process][cpu][start_time]").to_s).strftime("%A"))'
}
ruby {
  code => 'event.set("FechaPrimero", Time.parse(event.get("FechaPrimero").to_s).strftime("%a"))'
}
```